# Change Timeout/Duration for Automatic Text Replacement of Text Expansion Shortcuts in Chrome on M1 Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editing, productivity, typing

I just picked up a new M1 MacBook Air with Big Sur, and I imported all of my text expansions (found in system preferences > keyboard > text). I installed the version of Chrome designed for Apple Silicon.

Now, in Chrome (and Chrome Canary) for the M1 Mac, I noticed that if Edit > Substitutions > Text Replacement is enabled, if I type too quickly, Chrome will automatically replace the text of my shortcut characters with the full replacement, rather than replacing it when I hit the spacebar (which gives me a chance to hit escape to cancel).

As a result, I'm getting a lot of funky spellings when I type.

Example: tho -> though = thoughugh (when I type the "tho" part too fast, as in anything less than 1 second)

Outside of Chrome, this does not seem to be an issue.

I would like to change the timeout/duration or disable the automatic replacement in Chrome ***without*** disabling the ability to trigger the text replacement using the spacebar.

Thoughughts? Er, I mean, thoughts? :)

Comment: I've never known macOS to display that behaviour under any circumstance, let alone have a timer for it. If I start to type something I know is in my typing replacer it will just happily sit there until such time as I add a space or punctuation. If I have autocorrect on (which I usually don't) then it will show me the replacement it's waiting for me to confirm, but won't do anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your insight Tetsujin. After further investigation, it seems to be an issue specifically related to Chrome for the M1 Mac. I've updated the question to reflect this new discovery. :)

Comment: Is the problem in G-suite Gmail by any chance?

Comment: It's happening in Gmail for Chrome, among many other places. Lately it has also been happening in other areas of MacOS but seems to be intermittent.

Comment: In the native Trello app, it's even worse. No matter how slow I type, it just replaces the shortcut with the expansion immediately the moment I type that last character of the shortcut. So frustrating.